# SAS help optimising a linear equation with restrictions

Tags: optimization, parameters, model, sas, linear-programming

I'd like to be able to solve the following type of problem:

given observed data x(1)....x(n) and a known fixed 'target' b, solve for parameters a0, a1, & a2, which minimise:

`b-[a0+a1*x(i)+a1*x(i)^2]*x(i),    i=1 to n.`

with the restriction that the sum of the `[a0+a1*x(i)+a1*x(i)^2]` terms equals `n`, i.e. the mean of `[a0+a1*x(i)+a1*x(i)^2]` equals 1

I've tried PROC MODEL and PROC NLIN in SAS v9.4 but with no luck. Those modules allow for restrictions on individual parameters, but that is not needed here (a0, a1 & a2 can take any values). Perhaps PROC IML can solve this sort of constrained problem....?

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 2):

`PROC OPTMODEL` is what you're looking for. This will let you add as complex of constraints as you'd like. I'm not entirely sure if this is the exact solution you're looking for without any data to go on.

```
%let target = 0;

/* Generate data */
data have;
    do i = 1 to 100;
        x = rand('normal');
        output;
    end;
run;

proc optmodel;
    set OBS;
    num x{OBS};

    read data have into OBS = [i]
        x
    ;

    var a0, a1;
    
    con restrict: sum {i in OBS} (a0 * a1*x[i] + a1*x[i]**2) = sum{i in OBS} 1;

    min objective = sum {i in OBS} (&target. - (a0 + a1*x[i] + a1*x[i]**2)*x[i]);

    solve;

    print a0 a1;
quit;
```

Comment: Many, many thanks Stu - this looks perfect!

Comment: I still can't get this thing to work
data d1;do i = 1 to 100;x=ranuni(4245);w1=exp(1.0253056-3*x+0.4*x**2);output;end;run;
proc means data=d1 n mean std;var x;weight w1;run;
proc optmodel;
    set OBS;
    num x{OBS};
    read data d1 into OBS = [i] x ;
    var a0 init 1, a1 init -2, a2 init 0.5;
    con restrict: sum {i in OBS} exp(a0 + a1*x[i] + a2*x[i]**2) = sum{i in OBS} 1;
    min objective = (0.2736 - sum {i in OBS} (exp(a0 + a1*x[i] + a2*x[i]**2)*x[i]))**2;
    solve with nlp / tech=ip ms seed=21 MSMAXSTARTS=5000 msbndrange=50;
    print a0 a1 a2;quit;

Comment: I am able to run this successfully and the solution converges. What issue are you having?

Comment: Hi Stu,  when I run this code it converges to:          

           a0         a1        a2
        4.404    -271.35    -844.7

Which is a long way from the actual parameters used to simulate the data.                             FYI, I realise that I should have stated b-[a0+a1*x(i)+a2*x(i)^2]*x(i), in the original problem (I mistakenly referred to parameter 'a1' twice').

Comment: Gotcha. Should your `b` parameter be outside of the sum?

Comment: Yes, I think so. With some help from a SAS community user I got the following code to work: 
proc optmodel;
   set OBS;
   num x{OBS};
   read data d1 into OBS = [i] x;
   var a {j in 0..2};
   impvar w {i in OBS} = exp(sum {j in 0..2} a[j]*x[i]^j);
   con r1: sum {i in OBS} w[i] = card(OBS);
   con r2: &target-0.001<=sum {i in OBS} w[i]*x[i]<=&target+0.001;
   min objective = sum {i in OBS} w[i]**2;
   solve with nlp;
   print a;
quit;

Comment: Awesome! Great to hear.